# ExtJS: How to get decimal number value

Tags: extjs, format

I used decimalSeparator property of numberfield and set it to ',' (comma). Now I have problem reading value as number and doing math with it.

I first tried simple:

```
var v = form.getForm().getValues().myfield / 2
```

As soon s I type comma, v becomes NaN.

Then I tried:

```
var v = Ext.util.Format.number(form.getForm().getValues().myfield, "0.000,00") / 2
```

As soon a I type comma, v becomes 0.

I also tried combinations with /i in format string but id didn't help either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
var value = parseFloat("5000,5".replace(",", "."));
```

Comment: Roby, thanks this is very good, but still not "general" enough for my taste. I was hoping to find "set it and forget it" solution like configuration option for user/session/other variable. I guess it is javascript issue that it cannot accept decimal separator other than dot.

Comment: Not ideal, but implemented :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `getValues` does not work as you expect. From [the documentation of `getValues`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.BasicForm) (emphasis mine):

> Note: The values are collected from all enabled HTML input elements within the form, not from the Ext Field objects. This means that **all returned values are Strings** (or Arrays of Strings) and that the value can potentially be the emptyText of a field.

If you want to ensure that you have a decimal value, you will have to do something like the following:

```
var v_string = form.getForm().getValues().myfield; //get the string
v_string = v_string.replace(",", "."); //replace ',' with '.'
var v = (+v_string) / 2; //convert the value to a decimal and divide by 2
```

**EDIT**

You could also try using the `getFieldValues` (i.e. [`form.getForm().getFieldValues()`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.BasicForm)) method instead of the `getValues` method. This should act as though you had called `getValues` on every form field.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This workaround works great, but is there more "global" solution? I have web app with many, many decimal numbers and writing this kind of data retrieval for every field would be tedious.

Comment: I don't get getFieldValues, nor where and why to apply it.

Comment: Sorry about that; It's a property of the form. I've made it a bit more clear in my answer.